# "Infinite" mirror corridor isn't infinite (Cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mirror, reflection

I'm trying to make almost infinite room where walls, floor and ceiling are mirrors, but every next reflection is getting darker and darker, so I cannot reach effect near to infinity. I'm using a simple `Glossy BSDF` shader with white color and *Roughness* set to 0. I've already set *Light Paths* to:

*Total* 1024, *Diffuse:* 4, *Glossy:* 1024, *Transmission:* 12, *Volume:* 0, *Transparent:* 8.

I've also noticed another problem, strange reflection (yellow mark). There are only three holes without planes with glass, only holes. HDRI doesn't have this "rectangle" filled with same color, that's why I don't know why this reflection is soo ugly.

Could someone help me please? I've also marked walls, and floor with green lines to make it more readable.

Raw view:
[image]

Render in viewport:
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: Are you sure that the color is 100% white? It works fine for me...

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to upload two images, but only one appeared in preview, so I've decided to add link instead. A, yes, the Value was 0.8 instead of 1. Thank you. My bad. But still there's that strange ugly color in these reflections marked with yellow color. Sharp mono color blue area, while there's no such area in HDRI

Comment: could you please share your object (make it as simple as possible): https://blend-exchange.com/